# Identify encryption type

Tags: encryption

I'm hoping someone could explain to me how I can identify this encryption type:

```
465c477aa1e6d6690438aa3cda5182fe51ee28e5e72b253086
```

I really need to decrypt this and reveal the text but have been struggling for quite some time. Any help/info is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This question is impossible to answer, I've voted to close. One cannot inspect ciphertext and draw any meaningful conclusions about how it was encrypted. You've made no mention of knowing the key material, which almost certainly renders your attempt to decrypt this as pointless.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about identifying an encryption type. This is not a programming question and has no usefullness on this site.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that can be decrypted? By the looks of it, it seems like some sort of hashing function (sha1 perhaps), and those are one way.

Read about MD5 and SHA1, and hashing algorithms in general, I think it is most likely one of those.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll look into this. I'm pretty new to this as I'm sure you can tell :)

Comment: This is not sound advice. There is no way to determine if this is the output of a hash function. In fact, given the data is 25 bytes in length, it certainly isn't MD5 or SHA-1.

Comment: I agree, I just advised that he looks it up and compare to his code. he should also check if all encripted values have same length output, and also should provide some decrypted input with encrypt output if applicable, for comparison.